# Make HTMLUnit less verbose

Tags: logging, htmlunit

I am using HTMLUnit to crawl pages and my log keeps getting cluttered by HTMLUnit output. I.e. It send a whole pages HTML to the log if it returns a 403 status-code.

I tried the following to put it off:

```
System.getProperties().put("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog", "fatal"); 
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
```

Unfortunately without any effect, my log still looks like a mess. My project uses log4j, but I didn't configure HTMLUnit in any way to use it.

Comment: `webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);` worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Thomas -- Did you happen to figure out a configuration that helped silence HtmlUnit?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this:

```
webClient.setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
```

I usually end up adding this too:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog", "fatal");
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no method webClient.setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode

Instead you should use:

`webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);`